# How to get rid of tracking dots being included in foiling process?

Tags: print-design, print-production

I discovered that there are tracking dots printed on my paper called [Machine Identification Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_Identification_Code) (MIC), also known as printer steganography, yellow dots, tracking dots or secret dots. These dots are interfering with my [Minc Foil Applicator](https://www.google.com/search?q=minc%20foil%20applicator&sxsrf=APwXEdfVup2E5LuO4LEyB2GncV4EbmT9jQ%3A1686876043273&ei=i6-LZJOqEN_E4-EP8KCq6AQ&ved=0ahUKEwjTm9v6xsb_AhVf4jgGHXCQCk0Q4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=minc%20foil%20applicator&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIICAAQFhAeEA8yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB46BAgjECc6BwgjEIoFECc6BwgAEIoFEEM6DQguEIoFEMcBENEDEEM6CwgAEIAEELEDEIMBOgsIABCKBRCxAxCDAToQCAAQgAQQFBCHAhCxAxCDAToLCC4QgAQQsQMQgwE6CggAEIAEEBQQhwI6CAgAEIAEELEDOgsILhCDARCxAxCABDoNCC4QigUQsQMQgwEQQzoNCAAQigUQsQMQgwEQQzoKCAAQigUQsQMQQzoNCAAQgAQQsQMQgwEQCjoLCC4QgAQQxwEQrwE6CAgAEIoFEJECSgQIQRgAUABYoBNgmBVoAHABeACAAcUBiAHhGJIBBDAuMjCYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) which foils everything that is toner printed. And since these dots get included in the print, they also get included in the foiling process. How do I work around this problem or how do I get rid of these dots? Can those dots be disabled from the print output?

[image]

Comment: Interesting challenge. Maybe the Minc people had a black&white laserprinter in mind.

Comment: yeah that probably could do the trick. i think this is impossible to solve if you have a color laser printer? unless you are able to contact the printer manufacturer to modify the firmware to allow a user to change the printer settings on this. But I read that some laser printers don't have this feature, I should probably go for one of those. Do you have any laser printer in mind that can also print 12x18 inch sheets in color but don't support the MIC feature?